# Symfony3 Web Profiler throwing TwigErrorRuntime

Tags: php, twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm experiencing a weird error in Symfony 3 with the web profiler. When loading any page, it will throw an `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception and pass me this error message:

`Key "forms" for array with keys "Forms, forms_by_hash, nb_errors" does not exist in @WebProfiler/Collector/form.html.twig at line 31`

As this is a library, I'm not comfortable editing this file, but nonetheless it should work. Out of the blue, when adding a controller to create a new object with a FormType, this started to happen.
The error comes from this piece of the twig form.html.twig template:

```
{% block menu %}
    <span class="label label-status-{{ collector.data.nb_errors ? 'error' }} {{ collector.data.forms is empty ? 'disabled' }}">
        <span class="icon">{{ include('@WebProfiler/Icon/form.svg') }}</span>
        <strong>Forms</strong>
        {% if collector.data.nb_errors > 0 %}
            <span class="count">
                <span>{{ collector.data.nb_errors }}</span>
            </span>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
{% endblock %}
```

Line 31 is the `span.label.label-status-[error|disabled]` line, apparently it does work earlier on in the template. `collector.data.forms|length` works but `collector.data.forms is empty ? 'disabled'` does not.
How can I solve this?